# Django - Foreingkey relationship requires field

Tags: django, serialization, model, deserialization

I have the following Foreignkey relationship between two models:

```
class Text(models.Model):
    textcontent = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.ForeignKey(ModelA,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)
    commentContent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So, a text can have multiple comments, but a comment is assigned to only one text. 
In `serializers.py` I have the following:

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ('url',
                  'id',
                  'comment_set'
                  )
```

As you see, I want to show also the set of comments belonging to one text via `'comment_set'`.
But when I create a text instance (without providing comments) I get the following on the commandline :

> "comment_set": [
>           "This field is required."
>       ],

Why is it required ? I have set the blank & null arguments to True. 
How I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [**`read_only_fields`**--[DRF-Doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) in the meta class, as

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'comment_set')
        read_only_fields = ('comment_set',)
```

Comment: when I do this, can I later add Comment instances to the created Text instance ?

Comment: `comment_set` is a ***reverse relation***, you can't create `Comment` instances through `TextSerializer` unless you override the **`create()`** method.

Comment: which means, you can't create `Comment` instances using `TextSerializer` even though the error is not raised.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is: When I later create a Comment instance via the CommentSerializer then I can relate it to Text instance, right ? The fact that this field is read-only will not affect the adding process, right ?

Comment: Yes. This read-only will not affect the adding process **unless you try to put the data in the same field, here the `comment_set`**. You could use a new field, `comment` for adding new data.

Comment: hmmh..do I have other options ? Somehow I do not like this whole read-only stuff. I mean, it helped me. Now, it works. Thanks for that. But are there any other solutions I could test ?

Comment: Yeah...its possible by overriding the **__init__()** method. Since it's a aother question, please ask it as new question. Anyway, I hope my answer solve the issue specified in your post, pls accept my answer.